# Do I need an Illinois Driver's License?

Tags: driving, illinois

I'm an international student on a J1 Visa pursuing a Master's degree at a university in Chicago. For the duration of my program I will live in Chicago, but will be leaving the US after finishing my program in approx 2 years. I have a driver's license from my EU home country along with the international drivers permit, which to my knowledge serves as translation.

[The Illinois rules of the road state the following:](http://www.cyberdriveillinois.com/publications/pdf_publications/dsd_a112.pdf)

> Individuals may drive in Illinois without a valid Illinois driver’s
>   license if they meet one of the following circumstances:
>    [...]
>   Are an out-of-state student attending an Illinois college/university;
>   they and their spouse and children may drive with a valid license from
>   their home state or country.

Does this exemption apply to me? I'm unsure whether `out-of-state` means someone not living in IL but only commuting to IL, or someone without permanent residence, such as me.

Answer (score 3):

"Out of state" means "not a permanent resident of the state".  A Californian student doesn't need to get an Illinois Driver's License (they can continue to use their Californian license), and nor does a German one (they can continue to use their German one).